# Problem on error highlight using IntelliJ 10 CE with the scala plug-in

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm having some strange behavior in the IntelliJ editor when editing scala sources. It continuously report problem of kind "cannot resolve symbol" on various Predef functions like "require" and "->".

It seems to be only an editor problem because I am able to run scala code in Intellij and compile the sources using maven.

Am I the only one having this kind of problem ?

I'm using the Intellij version 10.0.3 CE and scala plugin version 0.4.735.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the latest IntelliJ IDEA EAP together with the latest Scala Plugin. This is known to solve a lot of problems.

Comment: Agreed with the recommendation to use 10.5 EAP and the nightly build of the Scala plug-in. Development of the plug-in has ceased for the 10.0 series. However, you will find this spurious error flag remains...

Comment: I upgraded to the EAP version with the last scala plug-in but the problem remains... I finally found the problem on the scala plug-in bug tracker SCL-2880. A patch exists it will eventually be pushed in a futur release. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the [project configuration guide](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2010/09/02/project-configuration-explained/). It's likely that you forgot to add Scala standard library to the module dependencies.